# Invariant Violation: Invariant Violation: React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child. I don't know why?

Tags: css, reactjs, firebase, react-native, expo

I keep getting the invariant violation and I really don't know why...

```
<TouchableHighlight key={index} style={styles.viewContent} onPress={() => this.handleAlarmPress(alarm)}>
<Image style={styles.iconWarning} source={warningIcon} />
<View style={styles.textContent}>
<Text style={styles.textTime}>{time}</Text>
<Text style={styles.textDetail}>{alarm.facilityName}</Text>
<Text style={styles.textDetail}>Room: {alarm.room}</Text>
<Text style={styles.textDetail}>Floor: {alarm.floor}</Text>
</View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

If I remove  Tag, working well. What do you think is the cause?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Your question obviously didn't format correctly, can you edit it to make sense?

Comment: Can you add the code snipper where the error is occuring ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation at https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchablehighlight

> TouchableHighlight must have one child (not zero or more than one). If you wish to have several child components, wrap them in a View.

Your `TouchableHighlight` contains two children (an `Image` and a `View`) but `TouchableHighlight`s are designed to work with exactly one child. Try wrapping your `Image` and `View` inside of another `View` like

```
<TouchableHighlight key={index} style={styles.viewContent} onPress={() => this.handleAlarmPress(alarm)}>
    <View>
        <Image style={styles.iconWarning} source={warningIcon} />
        <View style={styles.textContent}>
            <Text style={styles.textTime}>{time}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textDetail}>{alarm.facilityName}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textDetail}>Room: {alarm.room}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.textDetail}>Floor: {alarm.floor}</Text>
        </View>
    </View>
</TouchableHighlight>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's working well with <View>